Did von Neumann consider his mathematical formulation of quantum mechanics to be essentially complete?
With my faulty memory, I recall reading someone claiming that von Neumann did not consider his Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Mechanics to be complete and did expect further work to correct it.
While searching his book, I didn't get that sense. For the most part, it seems he thinks he's done it; he doesn't even include a concluding chapter or an afterword directing us to the next steps.  However, I note the following points:

The first sentence of his introduction is, "The object of this book is to present the new quantum mechanics in a unified representation which, so far as it is possible and useful, is mathematically rigorous." (My emphasis.)
He does point out a few times where he has done something mathematically dubious.
In the New Edition, edited by Nicholas A. Wheeler, an excerpt from a talk by Dyson is included as part of the Foreword. Dyson tells us that, after writing the book, von Neumann (who Dyson calls Johnny) went on for several years to study rings of operators: "Johnny began studying rings of operators to find out how many different types of quantum systems could exist."
This question on this StackExchange has an unsourced story of von Neumann saying the measurement problem is unsolved. Though, that seems at odds with his final chapters, where he describes the measurement process and the famous summary of those chapters as "consciousness causes collapse".

What is the evidence on von Neumann's personal opinion of his mathematical framework around the time of publication or after?

What would help? Posting more quotes from von Neumann?

Not sure what "complete" means, but if it means what Bohr and Einstein meant by completeness of QM then von Neumann was pretty definitive on the matter when ruling out hidden variables in chapter IV. And he was taken as such at the time, e.g. by Hermann in 1935, see Dieks, Von Neumann's Impossibility Proof. Hermann's 1935 treatise "has two main messages. First, it is not possible to prove the completeness of quantum mechanics on purely mathematical grounds, and Hermann takes von Neumann to task for his supposed erroneous opinion to the contrary."

@Mauricio Yes, quotes by him or others paraphrasing him. Anything that can discern how he felt about his work.

@Conifold Yes, the word "complete" is along those lines. Let's put it another way: at the time JvN published, did he foresee a second edition with longer chapters to shore up things? I guess the most satisfying evidence will come from his words outside his book because the first sentence of his book does cast some doubt on how complete his work is. I'm looking for him to clarify himself. (I really wish he had a concluding chapter.)

He probably  appreciated he had not addressed the problem of quantization adequately, and so his untenable/ambiguous special rule F in III Quantum Statistics was bound to be misread/misunderstood in future. He subsequently did not quite help publication of his acolyte's, H Groenewold's, thesis paper formulating the eponymous theorem which demolished his setup.

Valente discusses von Neumann's look back at the foundations of quantum mechanics in the 1954 ICM address. He reviewed his switch from Hilbert space to II1 factors, the search for natural algebraic axioms for QM, and "admitted, he never managed to set down the sought-after axiomatic formulation in a way that he considered satisfactory." However, this dissatisfaction of his is separate from predictive completeness of QM as understood by Bohr and Einstein. As is 'incompleteness' in philosophy of measurement that does not affect predictions either.

Slightly off topic but perhaps of some interest, Quanta published a recent (Sept 25, 2024) article that can be regarded as an epilogue to the excerpt in OP's bullet point 3. The article, subtitled A 1930s-era breakthrough is helping physicists understand how quantum threads could weave together into a holographic space-time fabric., discusses the central role of Von Neumann algebras in some contemporary investigations into quantum mechanics.

It is not possible to know what von Neumann thought, and his opinion could change during his life. Anyway,
he published at least one different approach to the mathematical foundation of quantum mechanics:
Jordan, P.; von Neumann, J.; Wigner, E.
On an algebraic generalization of the quantum mechanical formalism.
Ann. of Math. (2) 35 (1934), no. 1, 29–64.
This was later developed by I. Segal,
Postulates for general quantum mechanics.
Ann. of Math. (2) 48 (1947), 930–948.
